# ButtonProps from the package is incompatible with Button component from the package

Tags: reactjs, typescript, reactstrap

I'm using Reactstrap with Typescript and typings from `@types/reactstrap`. I'm trying to use the `Button` component in an HOC, so I need to explicitly reference the `ButtonProps` type. Here's the code for it:

```ts
import React from 'react'
import {withFormState, FormState} from 'informed'
import {Button, ButtonProps} from 'reactstrap'

export const SubmitButton = withFormState<Button, {formState: FormState} & ButtonProps>(
  ({
    formState: {pristine, invalid},
    disabled = false, children,
    ...props
  }) =>
    <Button type="submit" color="success" 
            disabled={pristine || invalid || disabled}
            {...props}>
      {children}
    </Button>
)
```

So basically I just combine `ButtonProps` from the package with `FormState` from another package, but in the end the `props` variable should have only the props matching the `ButtonProps` type (since `formState` is destructured from it).

However, TS says that `ButtonProps` do not match the props that I pass to the component, namely that the `ref` property types are incompatible. I don't work with refs in this instance, so it's unlikely that I messed them up. Most likely, I just do not understand how to properly define types in this case.

Here are the references to the typings that I use:

- [Informed's `withFormState` type](https://bitbucket.org/ventzkemediaberlin/types-informed/src/c1e367a51e55f384318cb7c05680ce5575fafa8f/index.d.ts#lines-571)
- [Reactstrap's `ButtonProps` and `Button`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/reactstrap/index.d.ts#L32)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd consider this a bug in the `@types/reactstrap` type declarations.  Notice that the same error occurs in the following simpler test case:

```
function test(props: ButtonProps) {
    return <Button {...props}/>;
}
```

`ButtonProps` includes `React.HTMLProps<HTMLButtonElement>`, which includes a `ref` prop of type `Ref<HTMLButtonElement>`, but `Button` cannot truly accept such a prop because React will intercept a `ref` prop specified on the JSX element and associate it with the `Button` component, not any `HTMLButtonElement` that may exist within it.  `ButtonProps` should probably be changed to use `React.AllHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>` instead of `React.HTMLProps<HTMLButtonElement>`.  Please [file an issue against DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues).

As a workaround, you can remove the bogus `ref` prop in the destructuring:

```
export const SubmitButton = withFormState<Button, {formState: FormState} & ButtonProps>(
  ({
    formState: {pristine, invalid},
    disabled = false, children,
    ref,  // <---
    ...props
  }) => {
    return <Button type="submit" color="success" 
            disabled={pristine || invalid || disabled}
            {...props}>
      {children}
    </Button>
  }
)
```

Comment: Thanks! I removed it in the destructuring and now it's "fine". I'll file the issue