# How to type Wrapper react function of Spinner of Reactstrap?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, reactstrap

I tried to make custom default props for Spinner so I tried making `SpinnerAProps` interface which extends `SpinnerProps` of Reactstrap which also Spinner uses like:

```
declare class Spinner<T = {[key: string]: any}> extends React.Component<SpinnerProps> {}
```

And this is SpinnerProps of Reactstrap

```
export interface SpinnerProps extends React.HTMLProps<HTMLElement> {
    [key: string]: any;
    tag?: string | React.ReactType;
    type?: string;
    size?: any;
    color?: string;
    className?: string;
    cssModule?: CSSModule;
}
```

It seems OK for me because `SpinnerAProps` interface uses same interface

But it complains

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(props: Readonly<SpinnerProps>): Spinner<{ [key: string]: any; }>', gave the following error.
    Type '{ tag?: string | ComponentClass<any, any> | FunctionComponent<any> | undefined; type?: string | undefined; size: any; color?: string | undefined; ... 359 more ...; animation: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicClassAttributes<Spinner<{ [key: string]: any;
 }>>'.
      Types of property 'ref' are incompatible.
        Type 'string | ((instance: HTMLElement | null) => void) | RefObject<HTMLElement> | null | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string | ((instance: Spinner<{ [key: string]: any; }> | null) => void) | RefObject<Spinner<{ [key: string]: any; }>> | null | undefined'.    
          Type '(instance: HTMLElement | null) => void' is not assignable to type 'string | ((instance: Spinner<{ [key: string]: any; }> | null) => void) | RefObject<Spinner<{ [key: string]: any; }>> | null | undefined'.
           ...
```

```
import React from 'react'
import { Spinner, SpinnerProps } from 'reactstrap'
import './Spinner.scss'

interface SpinnerAProps extends SpinnerProps {}

const SpinnerA = ({ ...rest }: SpinnerAProps) => {
  return <Spinner animation="grow" size="sm" role="status" aria-hidden="true" {...rest}></Spinner>
}

export default SpinnerA
```

Why is it and how to solve it?? Thanks

I found a clue It complains because of HTMLProps's AllHTMLAttributes, ClassAttributes

Answer (score 0):

I found that destructuring ref from props is a solution for this.
[ButtonProps from the package is incompatible with Button component from the package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52728722/buttonprops-from-the-package-is-incompatible-with-button-component-from-the-pack)

```
import React from 'react'
import { Spinner, SpinnerProps } from 'reactstrap'
import './Spinner.scss'

interface SpinnerAProps extends SpinnerProps {}

const SpinnerA = ({ ref, ...rest }: SpinnerAProps) => {
  return (
    <Spinner
      as="span"
      animation="grow"
      size="sm"
      role="status"
      aria-hidden="true"
      {...rest}
    ></Spinner>
  )
}

export default SpinnerA
```